# ASP.NET Passing values between classes using interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I usually use STATIC implementation when developing Desktop Application and I just got my head bumped on the wall when I use STATIC in ASP.NET (not a good idea)

I think I saw some feedback here before that you can use INTERFACE for passing values between Classes and Pages without using Session.

Can you guys give a good example on how to implement my question? Thanks

here's my sample code

```
public interface ISessionManager
{
    SessionStates sesState { get; set; }
}

public struct SessionStates
{
    public string SessionID;
    public bool isLoggedIn;
    public string Username;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is possible.  An interface is just a definition of a contract.  To pass information from a class (which I assume is code-behind or something on the server) to a page (which is client-based) involves either: a) cookie, b) viewstate, c) hidden value or other form value, d) ajax call, or e) a few others that are escaping me.  An interface is a definition, not a mechanism.

Comment: Thanks D. Alright, quick question. Is it possible to add the STRUCT values in Session as value? e.g - SessionStates ss = new SessionStates();ss.Username="testing";Session.Add("MySession", ss); but am not sure how to retrieve it.

Comment: sorry: SessionStates ss = (SessionStates)Session["MySession"];

Comment: @Nullstr1ng - yes you can definitely add the struct values to session. And retrieve them and use them as you have indicated above. That should work fine!

Comment: @In_Sane Do you think it's good to manage the session variables and values that way? using STRUCT. IMO, I think it's ok.

Comment: We do something similar on a project I'm on -- we have a typed session class that holds all our session variables, and we retrieve it as you describe above. I think it's better than having a free-for-all when adding info to session. At least this way, when you want to add a new item to session, you basically have to get the team lead to sign off since you're changing the class' structure. I say go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Session state objects,

Session["variable_name"] = assign any value in one class and use this session state object in any other class.

For example,

using System.Web.SessionState;

//Store the value in the session state object in one class

Session["sessionid"]=Request.QueryString.Get("session_key").ToString();

//Use the session state object in another class

String sessionid=Session["sessionid"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I decided to do it in another way and I called it SessionManager. I just want to get out of typing the Session variable name everytime I have to use it and this is to prevent some mistyping the session variable name .. so this I what I came up.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class SessionManager : IRequiresSessionState
{
    public SessionManager()
    {
    }

    string _sessionID = string.Empty;
    public string SessionID
    {
        get
        {
            if (Get("SessionID") == null) Save("SessionID", string.Empty);
            return Get("SessionID").ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this._sessionID = value;
            Save("SessionID", value);
        }
    }

    bool _isLoggedIn = false;
    public bool isLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            if (Get("isLoggedIn") == null) Save("isLoggedIn", false);
            return Convert.ToBoolean(Get("isLoggedIn").ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            this._isLoggedIn = value;
            Save("isLoggedIn", value);
        }
    }

    string _username = string.Empty;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            if (Get("Username") == null) Save("Username", string.Empty);
            return Get("Username").ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this._username = value;
            Save("Username", value);
        }
    }

    int _selectedCID = 0;
    public int SelectedCID
    {
        get
        {
            if (Get("SelectedCID") == null) Save("SelectedCID", 0);
            return Convert.ToInt32(Get("SelectedCID"));
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedCID = value;
            Save("SelectedCID", value);
        }
    }

    string _selectedCIDValPath = string.Empty;
    public string SelectedCIDValPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (Get("SelectedCIDValPath") == null) Save("SelectedCIDValPath", 0);
            return Get("SelectedCIDValPath").ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedCIDValPath = value;
            Save("SelectedCIDValPath", value);
        }
    }

    #region methods
    void Save(string name, object value)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[name] != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[name] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(name, value);
        }
    }
    object Get(string name)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[name];
    }
    #endregion
}
```